# Returning nothing in terminal when running code for Collatz conjecture

Tags: c++

I coded this 3n+1 problem and I am getting nothing in my vs code terminal. It's not so big that it will take time to compute. I don't know if there's a problem with my code or my IDE.
Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i, j = 0;

    for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        start:

        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            j = i / 2;

            if (j == 1) {
                goto end;
            }
            else {
                goto start;
            }
        }
        else {
            j = i * 3 + 1;
            goto start;
        }

        end:

        cout << i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger to step through your algorithm line by line. When you do this pay close attention to the value of `i` and `j`

Comment: It looks to me like this will never end unless `i=2`. As a general note though, don't use `goto` in C++, just stick to loops.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that in your for loop, you check for whether `i` is odd or even. If it's odd, you just `j` to `i * 3 = 1` and go back to the `start` label.

On your first loop through, `i` is `1`. This is an odd number, so we'll take the else branch:

```cpp
        else {
            j = i * 3 + 1;
            goto start;
        }
```

This now sets `j` to `i * 3 + 1` which is `4`. The value of `i` has not changed and is still `1` when we re-evaluate whether it's odd or even. Because it still odd, we take the else branch again.

An infinite loop has been created.